# Character conversion - fromCharCode problems

Tags: javascript, json, string, unicode, type-conversion

I have a Javascript UI talking to an endpoint. The endpoint returns a passphrase challenge as an array of JSON objects. Each object had character index in the passphrase and the character code point value.

```
[{"index":3,"nValue":101},{"index":5,"nValue":114},{"index":6}]
```

I'm struggling to convert the code points back to letters. I'm getting RangeError exception. I'm not sure why I can't parse the value to number and pass it to the fromCharCode method.

```
for(var i = 0;i<result.length;i++){
    console.log(typeof result[i].nValue);               //prints string
    console.log('returnVal=*'+result[i].nValue+'*');    //prints *e*
    var intChar = parseInt(result[i].nValue);
    console.log(typeof intChar);                        //prints number
    console.log('intChar=*'+intChar+'*');               //prints *NaN*
    console.log('converted='+String.fromCharCode(result[i].nValue));  //empty string
    console.log('converted='+String.fromCodePoint(result[i].nValue));  //trows range exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{"index":6}` has no nValue thus returning undefined